# PHP - fetching prepared stmt into class: Fatal Error "class not found"

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I want to fetch the result of a query into a class (into an array of instances of a class). But I get the following error message:
Fatal error: Class 'Category' not found in ...
This is the code of the two functions in my database manager class that are involved:

```
public function prepareStatement($_Statement)
{
    $this->preparedStmt = $this->pdo->prepare($_Statement);

    if($this->preparedStmt === FALSE)
        throw new PreparedStmtException ("Fehler: Statement konnte nicht prepared werden.");
    else
        return TRUE;
}


public function execute($_Params = array(), $_FetchMode = NULL, $_Class = NULL)
{
    # Cancel execution if no statement prepared
    if($this->preparedStmt === null) 
        throw new PreparedStmtException ("Fehler: Statement wurde vor execute nicht prepared.");

    try
    {
        # Execute PDO call with params
        $this->preparedStmt->execute($_Params);

        # If no data is returned throw NoDataException
        if($this->preparedStmt->columnCount() == 0)
            throw new NoDataException;

        // else
        // Determine which fetch mode should be called, if NULL or something != 1 || != 0 just call
        // fetchAll without params
        if ($_FetchMode == 1)
             $result = $this->preparedStmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

        else if ($_FetchMode == 2)
             $result = $this->preparedStmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, $_Class); 

        else 
            $result = $this->preparedStmt->fetchAll();
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        # Errormanagement --> Message im live Betrieb rausnehmen
        echo '<div style="color: red;">'.$e->getMessage().'</div>';
        $result = FALSE;
    }

    // If result is null throw Instance Exception, if result emtpy throw NoDataException
    if ($result == null)
        throw new InstanceException;
    else if (empty($result))
        throw new NoDataException;

    return $result;
}
```

This is a test function in a class to call them:

```
public function test () 
{
    $stmt = "SELECT * FROM tx_exhibition_category WHERE uid = 1 OR uid = 2";
    $this->mysql->prepareStatement($stmt);
    return $this->mysql->execute (array(), 2, "Category");
}
```

This is how i call test function:

```
$comment = CommentQuery::getInstance();
$result = $comment->test();
var_dump($result); // should be an array with instances of Category
```

And this is the class where it should be fetched into:

```
class Category {

private $id;
private $name;
private $projectId;

// getter and setter...
}
```

Some additional info:

- I use an autoloader to include my classes.
- I use namespaces
- yes, it is possible to create an instance of the class in all of the three functions, so
  class would be included and namespace used
- $_Mode == 1 works fine

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your `Category` class is in a namespace, you'll need to pass in a fully qualified class name into `fetchAll`.

Right now, PDO is trying to fetch into the class `Category` in the root namespace. It doesn't exist. You need to tell PDO about the namespace:

```
$stm->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'Vendor\\Package\\Category');
```

Or use a `__NAMESPACE__` constant if that makes it easier (and is correct):

```
$stm->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS, __NAMESPACE__ . '\\Category');
```

Or, even better, use PHP 5.5+'s `::class` constant to ge the fully qualified class name.

```
use Acme\Package\Category;
$stm->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS, Category::class);
```

Comment: Thanks! Very good explained! 
The `__NAMESPACE__` constant refers to the namespace where I call it but the namespace of my class is another, so I can't use it or is there another way?

Comment: No, you can't use it in that case (short of doing some parsing of it).  If you have PHP 5.5+ you can use the [`class` keyword](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class).

Comment: OK. Good to know with the class keyword. (sadly I have to use PHP 5.4)