# How do I use PDO::FETCH_CLASS with namespace?

Tags: php, pdo, namespaces

I'm learning PHP and right now I'm displaying some articles with PDO. I have some issue using PDO::FETCH_CLASS with the usage of namespace.

my folder architecture:

```
class/
- Post.php
layout/
-articles/
--articles.php
public/
-index.php (contains my router)
```

Post.php

```
namespace App\Articles;

class Post {
    private $id;
    private $name;
    private $content;
    private $date;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
    public function getContent()
    {
        return $this->content;
    }
    public function getExcerpt()
    {
        $res = $this->content;
        return (strlen($res) > 150) ? substr($res, 0, 150) . '...' : $res;
    }
    public function getDate()
    {
        return $this->date = date('d-m-Y', $this->date);
    }
}
```

data.db contains only four columns: id, name(text), content(text), created_at(int)

The part I have trouble with:

```
use App\Articles\Post;

$pdo = new PDO('sqlite:../data.db', null, null, [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_OBJ
]);
try {
    $query = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM posts');
    $posts = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'Post');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    $error = $e->getMessage();
}
```

I tried different typing instead of `'Post`like

```
'App\Articles\'
'App\Articles\Post'
'App\Articles\::POST'
...
```

I can't manage to make it works with namepsace.
It works with a `require '../class/Post.php'`.

Is there a solution for this problem or should I just use the require ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP - fetching prepared stmt into class: Fatal Error "class not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20176878/php-fetching-prepared-stmt-into-class-fatal-error-class-not-found)

Comment: @Dlk I tried but still can't find the class.

Comment: @Dharman I don't really understand the post. I tried but still not working. In my autoloader i have psr-4 to ```"App\\":  "class/"

Comment: What do you mean not working? Show us your Post class and show us the posts db schema.

Comment: @Dharman I've add the post class

Comment: And you have this line of PDO? `$r->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'App\\Articles\\Post');` What is the result?

Comment: @Dharman Class 'App\Articles\Post' not found

Comment: Are you sure that is included in the same file? How do you include it? Do you use Composer autoloader?

Comment: @Dharman I use ```require '../vendor/autoload.php```in my index.php where there is my router. And I also did a composer dump-autoload

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207941/discussion-between-dharman-and-jonathan-aurry).

Answer (score 1):

PDO does not look up aliased class names or resolve the current namespace. So you have to pass it explicitely:

```
$query = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM posts');
$query->execute();
$posts = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, __NAMESPACE__ . '\\post');
```

Using query instead of prepare will cause pdo error, I changed to prepare.

And you can't use NAMESPACE if its separate from the class, but you can use full path `'app\controller\post'`.

See this answer and question https://stackoverflow.com/a/20176944/12232340

Comment: You never execute the `prepare()`, but in this case you don't need prepared statement. You can simple call `query()`

Comment: you are right and sorry I copied and pasted code from question and forgot to `execute()` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add the folder Articles in class/ so App\Articles\Post couldn't be find.

Answer (score -3):

hi try to read somting about autoloading classes https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

if you dont have autoloading in code, simply using

```
use App\Articles\Post;
```

does nothing,or as you stated self using require is right solution